# Strange SQLException: Column not found

Tags: java, mysql, sqlexception

I'm getting a weird SQLException on a function I run against a database using JDBC.
SQLException: Column 'Message' not found.

I have this in my function:

```java
    st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT NotificationID,UserIDFrom,UserIDTo,Message,Timestamp,isNotified FROM notification WHERE UserIDTo=? AND isNotified=?");
    st.setInt(1, _UserID);
    st.setBoolean(2, false);
    System.out.println("st is: " + st);
    rs = st.executeQuery();
```

And I got that error, so I added this after the `st.executeQuery()` :

```java
    ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
    for (int index = 1; index <= meta.getColumnCount(); index++) {
        System.out.println("Column " + index + " is named " + meta.getColumnName(index));
        }
```

And when I run my code again this is what I get as a result:

```java
Column 1 is named NotificationID
Column 2 is named UserIDFrom
Column 3 is named UserIDTo
Column 4 is named Message
Column 5 is named TimeStamp
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Column 'Message' not found.
Column 6 is named isNotified
```

And here is a screenshot of my table's design, from MySQL Workbench
[image]

And the data in the table
[image]

I really can't figure out what's going one here.... Anyone can help out?

**EDIT**
I've replaced the `*` in the `SELECT` statement just to add something to the question that I just noticed.
If I remove the `Message` column from the select then I get the same error for the `TimeStamp` column. And if I remove both columns I get no errors then.

**EDIT2**
OK,this is the part i get the errors, i get both on Message and Timestamp:

```java
while (rs.next()) {
        NotificationID = rs.getInt("NotificationID");
        System.out.println("NotificationID: " + NotificationID);

        SenderID = rs.getInt("UserIDFrom");
        System.out.println("SenderID: " + SenderID);
        From = findUserName(SenderID);

        try {
            body = rs.getString("Message");
            System.out.println("body: " + body);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Message error: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            time = rs.getString("Timestamp");
            System.out.println("time: " + time);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Timestamp error: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I get the error on the `getString()` methods for each column
StackTrace for `TimeStamp`(the same for `Message`):

```java
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'TimeStamp' not found.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1167)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5733)
    at NotifyMe_Server.Database.getUnNotified(Database.java:444)
    at tests.Tests.main(Tests.java:39)
```

Comment: do you have any triggers on the table?

Comment: Do you get the error if you manually set the Int/Boolean in the SQL statement? I.e., try "SELECT * FROM notification WHERE UserIDTo=1 AND isNotified=0" and execute it without setting the PreparedStatement variables.

Comment: could you have some whitespace or weird character in the column name?

Comment: @abmitchell I've tried it the way way you said but I still got the same error

Comment: @BevynQ I have set 2 foreign Keys UsersIDFrom,UserIDTo and set CASCADE both on update and on delete, if that's what your are asking

Comment: @Taylor I've thought of that so I went and deleted the name, and write it again but even workbench prompted me with "no changes detected"

Comment: can you run "select Message from notification limit 10" in workbench successfully?  If so it's something in the application layer, so try debugging into the jdbc (or whatever you're using).

Comment: @Taylor I can run the query you proposed successfully, so you suggest I take a look at the rest of my code?

Comment: I suggest you debug into jdbc code to where the exception is thrown and try to track down the comparison that is failing that you expect to succeed.  The problem is likely in your code/config but debugging into jdbc will help you understand what's not lining up.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Did you try using a different get method on the date column to see if that changed anything?

Comment: I would say that the "getString" function cases your excceptions. It's an invalid object cast exception or so, but since you are using the SQL lib the original exception is truncated. Try to cast the correct object to your field.

Answer (score 1):

If you observe your code

```
try {
        time = rs.getString("Timestamp");
        System.out.println("time: " + time);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Timestamp error: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

you have used "Timestamp" in this format but if you changed it to "TimeStamp" as specified in your database, hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Change datatype of your isNotified column  as TINYINT in database and retry to insert

```
isNotified TINYINT(1)
```

Bool, Boolean: These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered false. Non-zero values are considered true.

Comment: I don't see a boolean option in the datatype, in MySQL
**EDIT** btw, I have the same type of field in another table, and i use the 'setBoolean()' in my java code and it works fine

Comment: Which version of MSQL you are using?

Comment: Not sure why you suggest this, I use Bit(1) all over the place and haven't had problems.

Comment: From the MySQL command line:
Server version: 5.6.13-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Answer (score 0):

Can you change

```
System.out.println("Column " + index + " is named " + meta.getColumnName(index));
```

to

```
System.out.println("Column " + index + " is named '" + meta.getColumnName(index) + "'");
```

so that we can see if there is whitespace in the "Message" column name?

The fact that the error message comes between column 5 and 6 is not important I think, because one is Standard Output and the other one Standard Error, these are not synchronized output streams.

(Also see the previous answer about Timestamp vs TimeStamp.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the table metadata is corrupt.  You should be able to correct this by dropping and recreating the table, although if the metadata is really borked you may not be able to drop the table.  If that's the case or you need to keep the data, backing up and restoring the whole database is the way to go, but check the SQL dump file before restoring and/or restore to another database name before dropping the broken database.  Depending on exactly what's wrong, your problem columns may be missing from the dump.

If refreshing the database is not an option there are ways to perform targetted repairs, but I'm no expert so I can't advise you on that.  Again, back up your database AND verify that the backup is complete (i.e. it has all your columns) before proceeding.  If this is a production database, I would be very wary about taking advice from the internet on manipulating metadata.  Minor differences in version, storage engine and environment can make or break you with this stuff, and given the nature of the problem you can't do a dry run.